# Thoughts on mics for recording vocals

Tags: microphone, home-studio, microphone-technique, studio

I was keen to buy a mic for recordings. I have shortlisted two of them -

Shure SM58

AT 2020

I have heard people say that condenser mics are mostly used for vocals. I wanted to buy At 2020, but the issue is that I don't have my room acoustically treated, so should I buy the dynamic one?

Also, many people say that they record with condenser mics under blankets and it works just fine. Is that really so?

Comment: You are asking something that is very subjective. Mic preferences, what does "good acoustics" mean, is the effect of blankets "enough" (for what?), general differences between condenser and dynamic microphones (technical, quality?). Additionally, condenser microphones are used for any kind of recording, be it instruments, live performances, ambient sound, in movies, even measurements. I believe that if you could be a bit more specific you would get better and more answers.

Comment: Put a good vocalist in front of a 58 & you're good to go. Put a bad vocalist in front of a $3,000  U87 & it will still suck. I've never tried the AT, so I've no comparison. Rent both & see which works best for you.